# Recursive Sql Query 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursive-query

I need to calculate the value of `indebtedness` column so that when `openingBalance !=0 then indebtedness = openingBalnce+SalesTotal-SalesReturn`. But, when `openingBalnce = 0 then indebtedness = indebtedness` of the previous `monthSales` with the same `SalesID`. If the `previous value = 0` get the `previous value` and continue get `previous value` till have value in this column:

```
SalesMonth SalesID  openingBalance  SalesTotal SalesReturn  Indebtednes
1          1        352200          0          5600         NULL
1          2        50000           1100       0            NULL
1          3        9500            6000       0            NULL
2          1        0               0          1200         NULL
2          2        0               300        0            NULL
2          3        0               500        1000         NULL
3          1        0               600        0            NULL
3          2        0               200        0            NULL
3          3        0               0          10           NULL
.
.
.
12         1        0               0          0            NULL
12         2        0               0          0            NULL
12         3        0               0          0            NULL
```

And Output like this:

```html
 when openingBalance !=0 then Indebtednes=openingBalnce+SalesTotal-SalesReturn

    when openingBalnce =0 then Indebtednes=Indebtednes (of the previous
    month of the same SalesID)+SalesTotal-SalesReturn.
```

```html
And this is the output i want.

 SalesMonth SalesID  openingBalance  SalesTotal SalesReturn  Indebtednes
    ---------- -------  --------------  ---------- -----------  ------------  
    1           1             352200     0          5600            346600
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           2             50000     1100         0              51100
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           3             9500      6000         0              15500
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2           1              0         0          1200            345400
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2           2              0         300          0             51400
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2           3              0         500        1000            15000
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3           1              0         600         0              346000
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3           2              0         200         0              51600
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    3           3              0         0           10             14990
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .
    .
    .
    12           1             0          0           0              NULL
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    12           2             0          0           0              NULL
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    12           3             0          0           0              NULL
```

Comment: can you add the expected output as well

Comment: for salesMonth=1 and SalesID=1 Indebtednes =346600

Comment: I mean expected sample output with data based on the above sample input in the question. you can edit the question and add the details

Comment: for salesMonth=1 and SalesID=1 Indebtednes =346600
      salesMonth=2 and salesID =1 indebtedness = 346600 and the same case with SalesID =2,3 when openingBalnce !=0 then indebtedness=openingBalnce+SalesTotal-SalesReturn but,when openingBalance =0  get Indebtednes of the previous month of the same SalesID ,problem is if the previous indebtedness is 0 get the value of the previous month and continue get previous value in the previous month till get value ,how can do this???

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `CROSS APPLY` or a co-related sub-query. Something like this. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50da7/1)

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @Sales TABLE (SalesMonth INT,SalesID  INT,openingBalance  MONEY,SalesTotal MONEY,SalesReturn  MONEY,Indebtednes MONEY)
insert into @Sales 
VALUES(1,           1,             352200,     0,          5600,            Null),
(1,           2,             50000,     1100,         0,              Null),
(1,           3,             9500,      6000,         0,              Null),
(2,           1,              0,         0,          1200,            Null),
(2,           2,              0,         300,          0,             Null),
(2,           3,              0,         500,        1000,            Null),
(3,           1,              0,         600,         0,              NULL),
(3,           2,              0,         200,         0,              NULL),
(3,           3,              0,         0,           10,             NULL)
```

**Select Query**

```
SELECT C1.SalesMonth,C1.SalesID,C1.openingBalance,C1.SalesTotal,C1.SalesReturn,C2.Indebt
FROM @Sales C1
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN openingBalance = 0 THEN NULL ELSE openingBalance + SalesTotal - SalesReturn END Indebt
FROM @Sales C2 WHERE C2.SalesID = C1.SalesID AND openingBalance <> 0  AND C2.SalesMonth <=C1.SalesMonth ORDER BY SalesMonth Desc
) C2
```

**Update Query**

```
UPDATE C1 
SET Indebtednes = 
(
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN openingBalance = 0 THEN NULL ELSE openingBalance + SalesTotal - SalesReturn END Indebt
FROM @Sales C2 WHERE C2.SalesID = C1.SalesID AND openingBalance <> 0  AND C2.SalesMonth <=C1.SalesMonth ORDER BY SalesMonth Desc
)
FROM @Sales C1

SELECT * FROM @Sales
```

Comment: please view again my post and give me answer ,i edited post with my output i want ,thanks for help me :)